# radio button shouldn't be selected by default

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

In lighting web component I have two radio buttons yes and no , my requirement is to  by default any buttons shouldn't be selected. I tried keeping values as null and undefine. But by default  it is selecting no or yes.

I tried with radio group

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.